# Как биндить функцию на кнопку клавиатуры в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, key, pyautogui, bind

Написал бота с помощью библиотеки **pyautogui**. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки (допустим **'enter'**) бот циклично проигрывался, а при повторном нажатии либо принудительно останавливался, либо программа закрывалась.

Долго искал информацию на это тему так и не нашел. Может кто-то знает решения?

***Пример бота:***

```
import pyautogui as root
from time import sleep
    
sleep (3)
root.moveTo( 242, 177 )
root.doubleClick()
sleep (17)
root.moveTo( 1709, 177 )  
root.click()
```

Comment: нажатие кнопочки можно проверить в модуле 
keyboard  .но sleep (17)  это вам нужно будет еще отдельный поток делать модулем threading ,который будет это нажатие ловить.

Comment: 1.Я не понял 90% выше сказанного 2. Убрать sleep не проблема 3.Я так и не нашел понятного гайда по keyboard у меня не получалось с ним работать. Может вы знаете источник где можно понятно научится пользоваться keyboard?

Comment: посмотрите https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Answer (score 3):

Как и советовали в комментариях используйте keyboard

```py
import keyboard

def on_triggered():
    print("Ваша функция!!!")

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift', on_triggered)


print("Нажмите ESC для остановки")
keyboard.wait('esc')
print("Программа идет дальше... )') # отработает после нажатия esc
```

Или тоже самое но с потоками:

```py
def on_triggered():
    print("Ваша функция!!!")

def key_watcher():
    keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift', on_triggered)
    keyboard.wait('esc')

thread_ = threading.Thread(target=key_watcher)
thread_.start()
print("Программа идет дальше... )') # отработает сразу при запуске программы
```

Таким образом перехват нажатий клавиатуры обернутый в поток не блокирует работу основной программы.

Comment: Огромное всем спасибо за потраченное вами время, я долго не мог разобраться, но благодаря вам смог.

Comment: А чем с потоком отличается от того что без потока?

Comment: В первом случае программа остановится и будет ловить нажатия, во втором программа продолжится ловя нажатия в отдельном потоке. Дополнил ответ.